# Insert a file whose full path is known into a change list in perforce p4v

Tags: perforce, windows-shell

I have a list of files , with full windows path of each file with me , i want to insert each of these file in a perforce changelist using windows shell or cygnus-win . Is this possible , if yes then what commands should i use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. You can use `p4 add <path to file>`. This will add file to default change list. `-c` allows you to specify change list to add to. For full help use `p4 help add`.

Note that you should also set up some environment variables to use p4 from command line or provide these details in command line before p4 action (like `p4 -u your_account add <path to file>`).

Shortly you have to setup P4USER (your account), P4PORT (server with port), P4CLIENT (workspace name). See `p4 help environment` for details.

For list of p4 options see `p4 help` and `p4 help usage`

Comment: The files also need to be located under the perforce root of the workspace you are working with.

Comment: If the file names are already in a list in a text file of their own, you can use 'p4 -x <listfilename> add' to have 'p4 add' read the list of filenames to add from this file.